# не могу придумать как записать в гугл таблицу информацию из телеграм бота pyton

Tags: python, telegram-bot, google-spreadsheet

Прошу помощи, ну или хотя бы направить в нужное русло.

Как научить бота вносить данные в гуглтаблицу о пользователе (user_id) и информацию которую воспроизводит бот в чат после нажатия кнопки

использовал gdpread

```
    googlesheet_id = 'токен тут к'
    gc = gspread.service_account(filename='джейсон гугла')
    sh = gc.open('название таблички')
    wks = sh.worksheet('название страницы таблички ')
```

вот строчка которая выводин информацию для гугл таблицы

```
      await bot.send_message(chat_id=query.from_user.id, text=f'Вы выбрали {item} его стоимость {config.items[item]}{config.currency}!\nOrder_id: {order_id}\n\nЕсли нажали случайно введите /delete_order {order_id}')
```

Все подобные топики прочитал тут. По ним делал интеграцию с таблицамии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй `.append_row`:

```
chat_id = query.from_user.id
text = f'Вы выбрали {item} его стоимость {config.items[item]}{config.currency}!\nOrder_id: {order_id}\n\nЕсли нажали случайно введите /delete_order {order_id}'

# Отправляем сообщение пользователю
await bot.send_message(chat_id, text)
# Записываем данные в таблицу
wks.append_row([chat_id, text])
```

Comment: Вас с 2k, кстати)

Comment: @Глеб благодарствую ))